# Completed 500 Internal Server Error; RestClient::NotAcceptable (406 Not Acceptable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, localhost, environment

I'm pretty new in Rails and on stackoverflow so I'll try to be explicite.
I was asking to change someone project, so I get the sources and try to make it works on
my own work computer (that's on Windows ...) to test it on my local browser (cf : rails s). The project is suppose to be working because it's already in production, so I assume that the problem come from my own work environment.
After installing all the needed gems, run bundle install and launch database serveur (the project is using mongodb), I run rails server. The command actually works but as soon as I try to connect on the application with any browser on the localhost adress (http://localhost:3000/) I get an error and I reaaly don't understand the cause...

This is the log I get :

---

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-04 14:51:30 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
** [Localeapp] 1354629090-- Handling translation updates
** [Localeapp] 1354629090 - polling
** [Localeapp] API CALL: get https://api.localeapp.com/v1/projects/hhMxHgKAzj9p1dFuS0GnTTnemJ5F9dXLDuCa1KacQSymUcmTFk/translations.yml?updated_at=1354612995
** [Localeapp] ATTEMPT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1192ms

RestClient::NotAcceptable (406 Not Acceptable):
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in `process_result'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `block in transmit'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
  rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
  localeapp (0.5.2) lib/localeapp/api_caller.rb:66:in `make_call'
  localeapp (0.5.2) lib/localeapp/api_caller.rb:28:in `call'
  localeapp (0.5.2) lib/localeapp/api_call.rb:6:in `api_call'
  localeapp (0.5.2) lib/localeapp/poller.rb:43:in `poll!'
  localeapp (0.5.2) lib/localeapp/rails/controller.rb:14:in `handle_translation_updates'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__744959596__process_action__507377612__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  mongoid (2.5.0) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
  mongoid (2.5.0) lib/mongoid.rb:133:in `unit_of_work'
  mongoid (2.5.0) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
  sass (3.2.1) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__286698992__call__202403334__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.4) lib/airbrake/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.4) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine-1.0.0-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine-1.0.0-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.4.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (56.0ms)
```

---

And this is the controller that's mentionned :

---

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @presenter = Home::IndexPresenter.new
    @article_presenter = Articles::IndexPresenter.new(Article.with_state(:published).last)
  end
end
```

---

If someone could help me it would be very kind. Ask if I forgot to mention something.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem is that the URL being requested by `rest_client` is returning the HTTP 406 code, which you can see by running `curl`, e.g.

```
curl --include https://api.localeapp.com/v1/projects/hhMxHgKAzj9p1dFuS0GnTTnemJ5F9dXLDuCa1KacQSymUcmTFk/translations.yml?updated_at=1354612995
```

(I just noticed that you are on a windows environment -- if you don't have access to `curl` there are several tools you can install that will allow you to make requests)

Then, within your controller, there doesn't appear to be any check to see if the response from the RestClient call was successful (2xx status) or not.  Because RestClient raises an exception, you get a 500 error in your application.

So, if you're not sure why the URL is not working, then you'll need to check the API provided by `localeapp.com`

But given that the API is an external service, you may also want to add some error handling within your software.  There are several things out there known as RestClient, but if it's by archiloque, the documentation provides a [good example of "result handling" here](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm sorry I didn't understand all parts of it ... I'm on a Windows environment but this project needed curl library so I installed it but I don't really know what is it used for.

Do you think it's an environment issue ? Because, I think that all these gems had been install.

Comment: `curl` is a unix command-line tool for getting (and POSTing, etc.) URLs like a browser would.  You don't need to have `curl` available -- I just used it to verify that the URL you posted was indeed returning the HTTP status 406.  Isolating the problem this way narrows down the problem to either 1) the API you are calling at `api.localeapp.com` is failing, or 2) your application is not sending the right URL, or perhaps isn't authenticated.  I would check at https://github.com/Locale/localeapp/wiki to or http://www.localeapp.com for details.

Comment: You were right ! Awesome ! Thanks a lot :D !
I finaly understand that the problem was in the config file of "localeapp". I shut down polling and sending to work in locale with those 2 lines in the config/initializers/localeapp.rb:
config.sending_environments = []
config.polling_environments = []
Thank you very much :) !!